# Allowing NULL value in json with API-Platform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have currently this entity and I want to show my property `firedDate` in my JSON even is the value is null.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={"groups"={"employee"}})
 * @ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties={"dateProperty": DateFilter::INCLUDE_NULL_BEFORE_AND_AFTER})
 * @ORM\Table(name="employee")
 */
class Employee
{
    // ...
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"employee"})
     */
    private $firedDate;


    public function getFiredDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->firedDate;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Currently, when the value is `null`, it's not shown in the response.

Comment: I don't think no, that thread have no link with API Platform.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think I found the right solution to this problem.
Set `skip_null_values` in `false` in your `normalizationContext`:

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get" = {
 *             //...
 *         }
 *         "put" = {
 *             //...
 *         },
 *         "patch" = {
 *             //...
 *         }
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post" = {
 *             //...
 *         }
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={
 *         "skip_null_values" = false,
 *         "groups" = {"object:read"}
 *     },
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups" = {"object:write"}}
 * )
```

Comment: Oh YES! I prefer your solution, "skip_null_values" do the job! :D Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find this anywhere in the api-platform docs. thanks for stopping my headache!

Comment: With ApiPlatform 2.6, If your entity includes a `PATCH` item operation the flag `skip_null_values` will be set to `true` (https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/2.6/src/Serializer/SerializerContextBuilder.php#L110). You can overwrite it thanks to @Winzza solution or remove `application/merge-patch+json` from api_platform.yaml in `patch_formats`.

Answer (score 10):

On ApiPlatform 3 [the default has changed](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#300-beta1) from `skip_null_values=false` to `skip_null_values=true`.

If you don't want having to set this on each resource, and would like to have the default as it as on ApiPlatform < 3, you can simply set it on the global config:

```yaml
api_platform:

    defaults:
      normalization_context:
        skip_null_values: false
```

Or if you use [PHP based configuration](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-config-builder-classes):

```php
return static function (Symfony\Config\ApiPlatformConfig $apiConfig): void {
    $apiConfig
      ->defaults()
        ->normalizationContext(['skip_null_values' => false]);
}
```

Comment: global solution does not work

Comment: Seems global solution working fine. Just clear the cache then.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to provide mroe additional information from @SteveMarooni answer, as I feel it lacks some info. As stated, setting changed from ApiPlatform 3 [changelog here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#300-beta1)

What you have to do to change this is either:

Add `#[ApiResource]` to every Entity

```
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: [
        'skip_null_values' => false
    ]
)]
class Entity
{
}
```

Or add this to your global config (if you don't have `api_platform.yaml`, you can simply add it manually)

```
api_platform:
    defaults:
        normalization_context:
            skip_null_values: false
```

You can find it in full config file documentation [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/configuration/#global-resources-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Are you under PHP 7.0 or above?
In PHP 7.1 you can have nullable return types for functions, so your

`public function getFiredDate(): ?\DateTime
{
  return $this->firedDate;
}`

With the `?` before \DateTime, the function will return `null` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I already have a getter like that, I just updated my post to add it :/ I think the problem come from @ApiFilter with Api-Platform ... maybe I have missed something..

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your entity is missing a getter like this one?

```php
public function getFiredDate(): \DateTime
{
  return $this->firedDate;
}
```

Comment: My entity was generated with make:entity, so yeah all the setter and getter are already there. All work good if the value is not "null", but I find that it is confusing to not have "null" in my json result. Api Platform say that I have to put "DateFilter::INCLUDE_NULL_BEFORE_AND_AFTER" but even with that instruction it doesn't work.

Answer (score -5):

Just get the solution from a friend on github, here is it:

```
* @ApiResource(
*      itemOperations={"get"},
* )
```

**BEFORE**:

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Employee",
    "@id": "/employees/1",
    "@type": "Employee",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oliver",
    "hired": "2019-10-10T00:00:00+00:00",
    "experience": 0,
    "salary": "1200.00",
    "job": {
        "@id": "/employee_jobs/1",
        "@type": "EmployeeJob",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mécanicien"
    }
}
```

**AFTER**:

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Employee",
    "@id": "/employees/1",
    "@type": "Employee",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oliver",
    "hired": "2019-10-10T00:00:00+00:00",
    "experience": 0,
    "salary": "1200.00",
    "firedDate": null,
    "job": {
        "@id": "/employee_jobs/1",
        "@type": "EmployeeJob",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mécanicien"
    }
}
```