# API Platform 3 does not return null data in response body

Tags: api-platform.com

In API Platform 2.7 the response body contained fields that had a null value, after upgrading to API Platform 3 the response body does not contain fields that have a null value. Is this deliberate or due to a configuration change I need to make.

I executed the same call from the api/docs page for 2.7 and 3.0 I expected the results to be the same.

API Platform 2.7 response for class Patient
{
"@context": "/api/contexts/Patient",
"@id": "/api/patients/8110",
"@type": "Patient",
"account": "/api/accounts/8110",
"accountId": 8110,
"isDependent": false,
"isGuardian": false,
"organization": "/api/organizations/765",
"email": null,
"title": null,
"firstName": "CA",
"middleInitial": "A",
"lastName": "Patient",
"suffix": null,
"photoMedia": null,
"sex": "male",
"birthDate": "2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
"addressLineOne": "5759 Witting Corners",
"addressLineTwo": null,
"city": "Marvintown",
"zipCode": "35507",
"state": {
"@id": "/api/states/681",
"@type": "State",
"abbreviation": "CA"
},
"phoneNumber": "617-491-0000",
"mobileNumber": null,
"workNumber": null
}

API Platform 3.0 response for class Patient
{
"@context": "/api/contexts/Patient",
"@id": "/api/patients/8110",
"@type": "Patient",
"account": "/api/accounts/8110",
"accountId": 8110,
"isDependent": false,
"isGuardian": false,
"organization": "/api/organizations/765",
"firstName": "CA",
"middleInitial": "A",
"lastName": "Patient",
"sex": "male",
"birthDate": "2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
"addressLineOne": "5759 Witting Corners",
"city": "Marvintown",
"zipCode": "35507",
"state": {
"@id": "/api/states/681",
"@type": "State",
"abbreviation": "CA"
},
"phoneNumber": "617-491-0000",
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314728/allowing-null-value-in-json-with-api-platform)

You only need to set skip_null_values to false in your normalization_context, because starting 3.0.0 beta 1 they decided it would become true by default.

If you need it to be false for all resources, you can set the default in your `config/packages/api_platform.yaml`:

```
api_platform:
  ...
  defaults:
    normalization_context:
      skip_null_values: false
```

Comment: Thanks works a treat.

Comment: You can consider upvote this answer, and mark it as the resolution. It would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Dean, I already upvoted but don't have a sufficient reputation to register, Thanks Again